# Can my code using two EXISTS clauses be simplified using a CASE statement?

Tags: mysql, case, exists

I have an input file that contains some rows with wild cards and some without. If there is a wildcard (*) in the input, I want to compare to a substring of the database element. If there is no wildcard, I will compare on the exact value of the input string and the full database element.

My current code looks like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM path.dbfile dbf
WHERE (
       EXISTS                                                
      (SELECT 1                                              
         FROM path.infile slt                          
        WHERE slt.ndc = dbf.ndc                           
          and LOCATE('*', slt.ndc) = 0) OR                   
       EXISTS                                                
      (SELECT 1                                              
         FROM path.infile slt                          
        WHERE substr(dbf.ndc,1,locate('*', slt.ndc)-1) =  
              substr(slt.ndc,1,locate('*', slt.ndc)-1)       
          and LOCATE('*', slt.ndc) <> 0)
      )
```

The code works, but I thought it might be simplified if I could combine the OR clauses into one CASE statement. I have not been able to get anything to work with a CASE. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your two subqueries refer to the same table.  You should be able to collapse them into one subquery by `OR`ing together their `WHERE` clauses.  I know it doesn't specifically answer your question about `CASE`, but it should simplify your query a bit.

Comment: Excellent idea! I knew I was repeating code that I did not need to. My purpose in trying to use CASE essentially is accomplished with OR ing the WHERE clauses together. Thanks! It works!

Answer (score 0):

Simply move `WHERE` clause from second `EXIST` to first one:

```
SELECT *
  FROM path.dbfile dbf
WHERE (
       EXISTS                                                
      (SELECT 1                                              
         FROM path.infile slt                          
        WHERE 
             (slt.ndc = dbf.ndc                           
                and LOCATE('*', slt.ndc) = 0) OR 
             (substr(dbf.ndc,1,locate('*', slt.ndc)-1) =  
                substr(slt.ndc,1,locate('*', slt.ndc)-1)       
               and LOCATE('*', slt.ndc) <> 0))
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe your logic works out as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbf.*
  FROM path.dbfile dbf
  JOIN path.infile slt
 WHERE LOCATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(slt.ndc,'*',1), dbf.ndc) = 1;
```

The function `SUBSTRING_INDEX` returns the whole string if the delimiter is not present.

Another option is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbf.*
  FROM path.dbfile dbf
  JOIN path.infile slt
 WHERE dbf.ndc LIKE REPLACE(REPLACE(slt.ndc, '_', '\\_'), '*', '%');
```

Which allows you to use `*` like `%` in the `LIKE` operator, assuming you don't have any percent signs in your filenames.
I have escaped any underscores as these too are a special character for `LIKE`, meaning one of any character.

Comment: I have a couple questions about your comment: 1. Would this take into account the case where the input file had NO wildcard and I want to compare the entire input string to the db string? 2. I don't understand the use of the inner REPLACE(slt.ndc, '_', '\\_'). What is this doing?

Comment: BTW - my middle name is Arthur!

Comment: @jasman_356 no problem, happy to help! Kindly accept the answer if you ended up using it :)

Comment: I did use it, and I passed it on. This is something we will use a lot in our work because of generic drugs with wild-carded numbering in our database.

Comment: @jasman_356 Great! Can you please accept the answer by clicking the tick top left.. then I get some points :)